# Can't copy authorization code when doing oauth for installed apps in phonegap webview

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, cordova, oauth-2.0

I'm doing the oauth procedure for installed apps, during which I send the user to a screen to copy the authorization code. This happens in a webview (it's a phonegap app).

When I reach the screen with the code I can select the code, but the context menu for copying it doesn't show! I can copy other stuff on the page, but not the code inside the input textarea. BTW the textarea is `readonly` but I don't think this should matter.

Is this a bug?

EDIT:

Same thing happens in regular chrome browser on android, but I found a way to copy there: long press and then quickly zoom in brings up the context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in chrome for android

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=251235